# Titanium module version mismatch and setup failure

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

When I run `appc setup`, it always fails.

```
$ appc setup
Finding latest version ...5.2.2 ✓
Version 5.2.2 already installed.
? Do you plan on developing Titanium apps? Yes

Checking your environment...

You have the latest Titanium SDK release 5.2.2.GA
2016-05-12T08:52:33.552Z | ERROR  | titanium exited with 1 exit code
```

Although `appc new` and `appc ti build -p ios` works (with warning),

```
$ appc new
[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.]
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

? What type of project are you creating? Native App (app)
? Which SDK would you like to use? Titanium SDK (JavaScript)
? What's the project name? myapp
? What's your application id (example: com.myapp)? com.myapp

*** new completed. ***

$ cd myapp && appc ti build -p ios
[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.]
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

5/12/2016, 6:15:05 PM

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.4
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.4.4
  npm Version                 = 2.15.1

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/takayuki/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone

Command
  /Users/takayuki/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.4/bin/node /Users/takayuki/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build -p ios --config-file /var/folders/4t/gzzx7fhx51nbc_wqxl80jx6h0000gn/T/build-1463044502821.json --log-level info --no-banner --project-dir /Users/takayuki/tmp/x/myapp

...
...
```

`appc ti build -p android` doesn't.

```
$ appc ti build -p android
[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.]
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Problem might be with the npm module installation - Follow the instructions from here - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-538